# Bash string manipulation

Tags: string, bash

I'm trying to get the numbers in bash from the following string.

`$qry2)); 275` --> `275` and not `2275`

`$qry1)) { 147` --> `147` and not `1147`

So what is the code for getting the last whole number?

Comment: Is the number always last or can there be clutter after it?

Comment: in previous cmd's I've already deleted the trailing text, so number is always last

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use `grep`, you can try:

```
echo '$qry2)); 275' | grep -o '[0-9]*$'
```

Answer (score 0):

With an `awk` you can get the last field :

```
awk '{ print $NF }'
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`:

```
sed 's/^.*[^0-9]\([0-9][0-9]*$\)/\1/'
```

Look for start of line, any number of characters followed by a non-digit and a string of digits to the end of the line; replace that with the string of digits.